# Linux. Xlib. Нарисовать прозрачный прямоугольник внутри окна

Tags: linux, c, x11, xlib

Глобальная цель стоит в том, чтобы нарисовать на рабочем столе просто оранжевую рамку, примерно как эта:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идея моей реализации такова: нарисовать прозрачное окно, а по его краям оранжевые прямоугольники, которые будут создавать эффект рамки:

```
#define W_WIDTH 640
#define W_HEIGHT 480

#define X_POS 100
#define Y_POS 120
#define BORDER_WIDTH 2

Display *dpy;
Window w;

XRectangle rectangles[4] =
    {
    { X_POS, Y_POS, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
    { X_POS, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT },
    { X_POS, W_HEIGHT - BORDER_WIDTH, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
    { W_WIDTH - BORDER_WIDTH, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT }
    };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GC gc;
    XGCValues gcv;
    int run = 1;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);
    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);

    w = XCreateWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), X_POS, Y_POS,
                      W_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT, BORDER_WIDTH, vinfo.depth,
                      InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);
    XColor color;
    Colormap colormap;
    char orangeDark[] = "#FF8000";
    colormap = DefaultColormap(dpy, 0);
    XParseColor(dpy, colormap, orangeDark, &color);
    XAllocColor(dpy, colormap, &color);

    gcv.line_width = BORDER_WIDTH;
    gc = XCreateGC(dpy, w, GCLineWidth, &gcv);

    XSelectInput(dpy, w, ExposureMask);
    Atom window_type = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    long value = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK", False);
    XChangeProperty(dpy, w, window_type, XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) &value, 1);
    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    XSync(dpy, False);

    while(run)
    {
        XEvent xe;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &xe);
        switch (xe.type)
        {
            case Expose:
                XSetForeground(dpy, gc, color.pixel);
                XDrawRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XFillRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XSync(dpy, False);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, w);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

Этот код работает почти как надо, за исключением того, что оранжевые прямоугольники получаются полупрозрачные (рамка нормально видна на темном фоне, но плохо на светлом):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы оранжевые прямоугольники были полностью оранжевые, а не полупрозранчые. Еще есть вариант нарисовать оранжевое окно без titlebar'а, а внутри него сделать прозрачную область нужного размера, чтобы в итоге осталась нужная рамка. Но тут вопрос в том, как внутри этого оранжевого окна сделать прозрачный прямоугольник? Что-то мне не удалось найти в интернете примеры или средства xlib, которые можно применить для решения этой проблемы.

Comment: Эх, и тут тоже награду предлагают…

Comment: @hidefromkgb, просто очень нужно было. Спасибо за ваш ответ в этой теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078155/draw-border-frame-using-xlib

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57078155/draw-border-frame-using-xlib

Comment: @insolor, что именно? =) В целом ответ hidefromkgb решает поставленную в вопросе проблему

Comment: @rudolfninja, добавил комментарий "ассоциация") "работает или нет" - это в том смысле, что не знаю работает ли ассоциация автоматически или нет. См. [Ассоциация вопросов между сайтами доступна!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4409/Ассоциация-вопросов-между-сайтами-доступна)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Данный ответ является переводом. Оригинал [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57136195).

В приведённом коде два основных недочёта:

1. Не были предварительно занулены структуры `attr` и `gcv`
2. Цвет добавлен не в ту палитру, нужно в `attr.colormap`

Исправленный код:

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>

#define W_WIDTH 640
#define W_HEIGHT 480

#define X_POS 100
#define Y_POS 120
#define BORDER_WIDTH 2

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    XRectangle rectangles[4] = {
        { X_POS, Y_POS, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
        { X_POS, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT },
        { X_POS, W_HEIGHT - BORDER_WIDTH, W_WIDTH, BORDER_WIDTH },
        { W_WIDTH - BORDER_WIDTH, Y_POS, BORDER_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT }
    };
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    XSetWindowAttributes attr = {0};
    XGCValues gcv = {0};
    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    GC gc;

    Window w;

    int run = 1;

    XMatchVisualInfo(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);

    XColor color;
    char orangeDark[] = "#FF8000";
    XParseColor(dpy, attr.colormap, orangeDark, &color);
    XAllocColor(dpy, attr.colormap, &color);

    w = XCreateWindow(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), X_POS, Y_POS,
                      W_WIDTH, W_HEIGHT, BORDER_WIDTH, vinfo.depth,
                      InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);

    gcv.line_width = BORDER_WIDTH;
    gc = XCreateGC(dpy, w, GCLineWidth, &gcv);

    XSelectInput(dpy, w, ExposureMask);
    long value = XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK", False);
    XChangeProperty(dpy, w, XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False),
                    XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace, (unsigned char *) &value, 1);
    XMapWindow(dpy, w);
    XSync(dpy, False);

    while(run) {
        XEvent xe;
        XNextEvent(dpy, &xe);
        switch (xe.type) {
            case Expose:
                XSetForeground(dpy, gc, color.pixel);
                XDrawRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XFillRectangles(dpy, w, gc, rectangles, 4);
                XSync(dpy, False);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(dpy, w);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

[image]

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы область окна внутри рамки как будто отсутствовала? То есть не только прозрачный цвет, но и, например, если у меня рамка поверх IDE, то кликнув внутрь рамки, фокус будет на IDE (в редакторе кода, если я кликну туда), но рамка все равно будет видна?

Comment: @rudolfninja Да, это возможно. У меня есть готовый пример на GTK+, но для голых иксов могу разве что подсказать функцию: [XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/fixesproto/tree/fixesproto.txt#n388) — с аргументом `destKind`, равным `ShapeInput`.

Comment: То есть идея в том, чтобы создать прозрачное окно (как я это уже делаю), затем создать пустой регион, с помощью функции [XUnionRectWithRegion](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/regions/XUnionRectWithRegion.html) объединить этот регион со всеми моими прямоугльниками из массива `rectangles` и просто вызвать `XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion` с полученным регионом? При этом в обработке события Expose ничего менять не нужно?

Comment: @rudolfninja Да, теоретически это должно сработать.

Comment: @rudolfninja Я даже больше скажу: окно можно создавать и без RGBA Pixmap (многие до сих пор не используют композитинг), а тоже тупо на оконных регионах.

Comment: вроде, вариант сработал. Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить про создания окна тупо на регионах?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96530/discussion-between-rudolfninja-and-hidefromkgb).